# Unable to update the discount command to subclass value since bas class value is set to 0

Tags: python, class, object, oop, attributes

I've been trying to see if I can change the discount of an item that is necessary for computation. My challenge is that, I cannot update the discount since it was set to 0.

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, food, amount, cost, discount=0):
        self.food = food
        self.amount = amount
        self.cost = cost
        self.discount = discount
        if self.discount == 0:
            self.cost = self.amount *100
        else:
            self.cost = self.amount * 100 * (1-self.discount)

class Malamute(Dog):
    def __init__(self, food, amount, cost, behavior, discount=0):
        super().__init__(food, amount, cost, discount=0)
        self.behavior = behavior
        if self.behavior == "very good":
            self.discount = 0.20
        if self.behavior == "good":
            self.discount = 0.10
        if self.behavior == "bad":
            self.discount = 0

class Golden(Dog):
    def __init__(self, food, amount, cost, damage, discount=0):
        super().__init__(food, amount, cost, discount=0)
        self.damage = damage
        self.discount = -self.damage



class Golden_Malamute(Malamute,Golden):
    def __init__(self, food, amount, cost, behavior, damage, discount=0):
        Malamute().__init__(self,food, amount, cost, behavior, discount=0)
        Golden().__init__(self,food, amount, cost, damage, discount=0)
        self.discount=discount

            
Brownie = Dog("Pellet", 10, 0,)
print("Brownie", Brownie.cost)
Mala=Malamute("Pellet",10,0,"good")
print("Mala",Mala.cost)
Goldie=Golden("Pellet",10,0, 0.10)
print("Goldei",Goldie.cost)
#Blackie=Golden_Malamute("Pellet", 10, 5, "good", 0.05)
#print("Blackie", Blackie.cost)
```

When there should be a discount, it does not directly apply since the discoutn is set to zero. I am unbale to shift the commant to other sub classes as there are instances where dog itslef will be called and if a subclass is called, it will have to undergo two processes.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to try the technique of walking through your program and speaking it out loud.

For example, this is how I read your listing and how I can detect an issue.

1. I create a new `GoldenDog`
2. The `GoldenDog` calls the `super.__init`
3. The super init calculates the cost based on the discount of zero
4. I then run the rest of the `GoldenDog.__init`
5. I set the discount to `0.10`

The problem is you are setting the discount *after* the cost has been calculated.

To solve this, you ought to calculate the cost when a caller asks for the cost. That way, it will be able to use the current value of the discount (rather than only being able to use the discount that applied when created).

Alternatively, you need to pass the discount to the `super.__init` call.

```
class Golden(Dog):
    def __init__(self, food, amount, cost, damage, discount=0):
        super().__init__(food, amount, cost, discount=-damage)
        self.damage = damage
```

Your next task will be to fix the discount logic as it currently *increases* the price, rather than reducing it.